# KML: GroundOverlay issues with the 180 line

Tags: kml

I have an image I need to overlay as a GroundOverlay that crosses the 180 line.

ex:  `<north>65.93</north><south>52.84</south><east>-178.55</east><west>-191.65</west>`

I only get -178.55 to -180 - the rest is just missing.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth in particular and many mapping applications in general often have errors with lines or overlays crossing the antimeridian (-180/+180 longitude).

Some related errors:
https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1145
https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1340
https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1348

The only way around this error is splitting the ground overlay into two images and have each touching but not crossing the 180 line.

Note that longitude in Google Earth is in the range [-180, +180] so -191.65 normalized is +168.35.

Use these regions in your KML:

```
<north>65.93</north><south>52.84</south><east>-178.55</east><west>-180</west>
<north>65.93</north><south>52.84</south><east>180</east><west>168.35</west>
```

Comment: Well, this ends up being more of a GE version issue.  GE6 works well with a west of -191, but GE7 stops at the 180.  GE is going backwards a bit on this issue.  Here's an example: [link](http://nosimagery.noaa.gov/rnc/kml/50_2.kmz)